# Error when click at the anchor - HtmlUnit

Tags: javascript, iframe, htmlunit

Everyone! I'm here again because I have a problem. When I click at the anchor the server shows a log at error and the page doesn't update and I can not get the iframe tag.

The link page: "https://compras.cetiqt.senai.br/portal/Mural.aspx"

Here follows my code::

```
 try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED)) {
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

    HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage("https://compras.cetiqt.senai.br/portal/Mural.aspx");
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20_000);

    DomNodeList tds = htmlPage.getElementsByTagName("td");
    HtmlTableDataCell td = (HtmlTableDataCell) tds.get(1);
    td.click();
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20_000);

    HtmlAnchor linkEdital = (HtmlAnchor) htmlPage.getByXPath("//a[@data-acao='edital']").get(0);
    linkEdital.click();
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20_000);
```

}

The server log:

> 2021-05-07 11:56:53.167  INFO 1632 --- [cTaskExecutor-1]
> .g.h.NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController : Re-synchronized call to
> https://compras.cetiqt.senai.br/portal/WebService/Servicos.asmx/PesquisarResumoEdital
> 2021-05-07 11:56:56.184 ERROR 1632 --- [cTaskExecutor-1]
> c.g.h.j.DefaultJavaScriptErrorListener   : Error during JavaScript
> execution
>
> com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: innerText is read-only
> for tag 'html'
> (https://compras.cetiqt.senai.br/Portal/Scripts/portaljs1?v=Ei-iqWxCMWoSqcf1vkTQ_kcBnknTwdegoFEvCAf9vgc1#1)
> Caused by:
> net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EvaluatorException:
> innerText is read-only for tag 'html'
> (https://compras.cetiqt.senai.br/Portal/Scripts/portaljs1?v=Ei-iqWxCMWoSqcf1vkTQ_kcBnknTwdegoFEvCAf9vgc1#1)
> at
> com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory$HtmlUnitErrorReporter.runtimeError(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:460)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Looks like a outdated implementation inside HtmlUnit. Please open a issue at github, will try to fix setting innerHtml for html tags.

Comment: Thanks @RBRi! I will to do this.

Comment: @Rbri I open the issue the number is #351. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with setting innerText is fixed in Version 2.50.0.

Comment: Thanks my friend! I will test today and will post here the result.